# How to convert a pandas column to datetime data type?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe that just has timedate stamps of data type "object". I want to convert the whole dataframe to a datetime data type. Also I would like to convert all the columns to the linux epoch nano seconds. So, I can use this dataframe in pca. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A1RH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=3).astype(str)
time_df = pd.DataFrame({'s': rng, 'a': rng})  
print (time_df)
           s          a
0 2017-04-03 2017-04-03
1 2017-04-04 2017-04-04
2 2017-04-05 2017-04-05
```

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with converting to datetimes and then to native epoch format by convert to numpy array and then to integers:

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, infer_datetime_format=True).values.astype(np.int64)
#pandas 0.24+
#f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, infer_datetime_format=True).to_numpy().astype(np.int64)
time_df = time_df.apply(f) 
print (time_df)
                     s                    a
0  1491177600000000000  1491177600000000000
1  1491264000000000000  1491264000000000000
2  1491350400000000000  1491350400000000000
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: @JumaHamdan - Super ;) Friend advice - [Don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)